# VBA: naming tables in a For loop

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, format

I'm populating cells using a For loop, with the results looking like this:

[image: example]

I'd like to format each set as a table, with each table name reflecting the number of the set (so "Table 1", "Table 2" etc). I thought I could do this with the VBA code:

```
> ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, ws.Range(ws.Cells(start_row,
> start_column), ws.Cells(table_height, table_width)), , xlYes).Name =
> "Table" & t_count
```

but I get the error message:

> Run-time error '1004':
>
> A table can't overlap another table.

Any ideas how I can get round this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Based on the error message, the tables overlap. But you did not provide full code, so nothing can be suggested, other than the obvious: check the ranges.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try the next way. There must exist minimum one empty row between the two consecutive ranges to become tables. There must not exist any gap/empty cell in the first rage column:

```
Sub createTablesFromRanges()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, start_row As Long, last_row As Long
  Dim start_column As Long, last_col As Long, t_count As Long, i As Long
  
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  lastR = ws.Range("A" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'calculated based on A:A column
  start_column = 1      'it can be different, if not the first column (A:A)
  t_count = 1           'first number before loop incrementation
  For i = 1 To lastR
        start_row = i   'range starting row
        last_col = ws.cells(i, ws.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'range last column number
        last_row = ws.Range("A" & i).End(xlDown).row                  'range last row

        'create table:
        ws.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, ws.Range(ws.cells(start_row, start_column), _
                ws.cells(last_row, last_col)), False, xlYes).Name = "Table" & t_count
        start_row = ws.cells(last_row, 1).End(xlDown).row - 1        'new starting row based on the next range header
         i = start_row: t_count = t_count + 1                        'increment i and t_count
         If i >= lastR Then Exit For 'after the last range, start_row returns the sheet total number of rows
  Next i
End Sub
```